# JAVA how to retrieve a string based on another

Tags: java, regex, java-stream

I have a list that contains some tags:

```
[[food_1]], [[drink_2]], [[food_1]]
```

I want to retrieve all tags that match an input

example:

```
input: [[food_*]]
result:[[food_1]],  [[food_2]]
```

input and tags have always the same format

this is my code snippet

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(input.replace("*","\\d")).matcher(element from tags list)
while(m.find()){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using collections, you can start to use streams, check this construction :

```
yourList
.stream()
.filter(line -> line.matches("YOUR REGEX"))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the input as is: if your tag format is `[[character_*]]`, then it is most likely that:

```
Pattern.compile(input.replace("*","\\d"))
```

Turns to:

```
Pattern.compile("[[character_*]]".replace("*","\\d"))
```

And

```
Pattern.compile("[[character_\\d]]"))
```

Since you can do a union of range, eg: [[a-z]&&[^b]], I think that pattern will only ever match one character at a time:

- You can test that here, or from your code: https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd5puaar
- It find 'd' for your example.

**TL;DR:** you must escape your pattern or fix it:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("[[character_*]]").replace("*","\\E\\d\\Q")))
// turns to: \Q[[character_\E\d\Q]]\E
```

The `\E` and `\Q` are what Java uses in `Pattern.quote` to escape a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Square bracket [] is regex metacharacter, hence need to escape that.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String pattern = "(\\[\\[food_[*]]])";
        pattern = pattern.replace("*", "\\d");
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(
                "[[food_1]], [[drink_2]], [[food_3]]");
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[food_1]]
[[food_3]]
```